How to get the list of colors used by a default color cycler in Matplotlib?
I would like to explicitly assign colors from colorList to consecutive points on a graph and have them identical to what implicit use of color cycler would produce. For example:
for i, c in enumerate(colorList):
  plt.scatter(i, i, color=c)

would produce the same colors as:
for i, _ in enumerate(colorList):
  plt.scatter(i, i)

How to get colorList?

I don't understand your question. Do you want to get the colors of the default colormap?

@mozway I was looking for plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']
